# How to remove "delete" button in default "Edit" form of sonata admin?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, sonata-admin

I wrote a code to list data taken from a simple database and there I put an action to edit data. When I click on this Edit button, it goes to the default "Edit" page. There is a button called "delete" there. I want to remove that button...

Comment: Accept the working answer please!

Comment: Is there a way to remove the delete route from embedded forms..? $collection->remove('delete') only removes the delete option from the admin form but not when the form is embedded to some other form

Answer (score 13):

In your EntityAdmin class add following

```
public function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
  $collection->remove('create');
}
```

Comment: Best solution I could come up with, too.

Answer (score 4):

I needed to hide the delete button from the edit form but not remove the delete functionality from the listing.

This is how I did it ... in case someone needs to do something similar

**Step 1**: Copy SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_edit_form.html.twig into your bundle, and comment out code / update as required

```
//YourBundle/Resources/views/EntityAdmin/base_edit_form.html.twig
{% block form %}

...

    {#{% if admin.hasroute('delete') and admin.isGranted('DELETE', object) %}#}
    {#{{ 'delete_or'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}#}
    {#<a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('delete', object) }}">{{ 'link_delete'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}</a>#}
    {#{% endif %}#}

...

{% endblock %}
```

**Step 2**: Add a new view resource edit.html.twig to extend the default edit template

```
//YourBundle/Resources/views/EntityAdmin/edit.html.twig
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_edit.html.twig' %}

{% use 'YourBundle:EntityAdmin:base_edit_form.html.twig' with form as parentForm %}

{% block form %}
    {{ block('parentForm') }}
{% endblock %}
```

**Step 3**: Update your Admin class to use the above template

```
//YourBundle/Admin/EntityAdmin.php
class EntityAdmin extends Admin{
...
    public function getTemplate($name)
    {
        switch ($name) {
            case 'edit':
                return 'SomeBundle:EntityAdmin:edit.html.twig';
                break;
            default:
                return parent::getTemplate($name);
                break;
        }
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

base_edit_form.html.twig:

```
{% if admin.hasroute('delete') and admin.isGranted('DELETE', object) %}
    {% trans from 'SonataAdminBundle' %}delete_or{% endtrans %}
    <a class="btn danger" href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('delete', object) }}">{% trans from 'SonataAdminBundle' %}link_delete{% endtrans %}</a>
{% endif %}
```

I see 3 ways to make this happen:

- remove delete route and it will remove all delete buttons from all places for give admin
- redefine hasroute function in your admin, it will give the same effect
- remove delete permissions for the object, depends what do you use for permissions

Answer (score 2):

Firstly use the class RouteCollection in your CustomClassAdmin :

```html
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;
```

and add the following code:

```html
    public function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
    {
        $collection->remove('delete');
    }
```